# javascript draggable slider that snaps back to middle position on mouseUp

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to implement a jog-dial like behavior in a scrollbar/slider like so:

in the beginning the handle is positioned in the middle of the "scrollbar/slider" area. When you click on the handle and drag it to the left or right (while keeping clicked) some other actions (updating of another area on the page) are performed -- the more the slider is dragged to either the left or right end, the faster. As soon as the mouse button is released, the handle should snap back to the middle of the slider area.

is there anything basically like this available as jquery/ui plugin/component/script that can be utilized and extended for this behavior?

update to clarify:

I already have a slider like so http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

I would like this slider to behave in the following manner:

- the handle of the slider should start out in the middle/center of the
- slider when you click on the handle you can drag it to the left or right (as long as you keep the mouse button pressed)
- when you release the mouse button, the handle of the slider should snap back to the starting position (center/middle)
- depending on how far and which side the handle is currently, i'd like to scroll other content (that other content is not part of this question)

hope this helps explain my intentions and question a bit better.

Comment: When I was thinking about exactly the same thing I didn't find anything like that. But really, this is the only reasonable way to navigate on endless pages. I was also searching for a way to download parts the user is about to perceive while deleting parts to save memory. I came to the conclusion that it's not possible to create it without building everything completely from the scratch. All "standard" controls are based on non-compatible philosophies. I used an image for the handle and wrote the whole logic myself. But in the end I couldn't decide on a reasonable API and aborted the project.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the slider value back to zero in the stop event handler then you get the snap back you need, here's code from a zoom speed control I just made:

```
$('#zoomslider').slider({
    slide: function(event,ui){
            setzoomspeed(ui.value)
        },

    stop: function(event,ui) {
        $('#zoomslider').slider("value",0);
        setzoomspeed(0);
    },  
    min:-20,
    max:20,
    value:0
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/)

In the events tab, you can see that you can set a `change` handler.

you can then get the current value of the slider in the handler, e.g.

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({
   change: function(event, ui) {
       var current_value = ui.value;
       //do something
   }
});
```

Comment: yeah, reading the position of the jquery ui slider is not the problem.. making it behave like described is what I'm after.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is to vague to answer it completely. Maybe you should split it into multiple problems first and ask as soon as you don't know how to go on.